# PHP If() .. Else if () Then Insert Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

After checking if uploaded CSV file has these characters on their filenames, I am trying to insert values from a CSV File into my database. So if filename has **m1** on its filename, I will insert/update these fields in my database table, so does with files with **m2**, **m3**, and **m4** on their filenames. Here's the code:

```
<?php
        $uploadstatus   = 1;
        $found          = 0;
        $filename = $file_path;
        $file_m1 = "m1";
        $file_m2 = "m2";
        $file_m3 = "m3";
        $file_m4 = "m4";

        if (file_exists($filename) && $uploadstatus) {
            if (!$found) {
            include ('conn.php');

            //get the file 
            $handle = fopen($filename,"r");

                do { 
                    if (isset($data[0])) { 
                        $data0  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);  //rcode
                        $data1  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);  //pcode
                        $data2  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);  //mcode
                        $data3  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);  //bcode
                        $data4  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);  //ecode
                        $data5  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);  //filetype
                        $data6  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);  //rec_count
                        $data7  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);  //gen_count
                        $data8  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);  //be_count
                        $data9  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]);  //qc_count
                        $data10 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]); //tran_count
                        $data11 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[11]); //rm_count
                        $data12 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[12]); //sc_count
                        $data13 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[13]); //in_count
                        $data14 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[14]); //en_count
                        $data15 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[15]); //co_count
                        $data16 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[16]); //ve_count
                        $data17 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[17]); //ed_count


                        // file_m1 = rec_count, gen_count,be_count,qc_count,tran_count 
                        if (strpos($filename , $file_m1)) {
                            $query =  "INSERT INTO tbltest (rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,rec_count,gen_count,be_count,qc_count,tran_count,) 
                                   VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$data6','$data7','$data8','$data9','$data10')
                                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rec_count=values(rec_count),gen_count=values(gen_count),be_count=values(be_count),
                                   qc_count=values(qc_count),tran_count=values(tran_count)";
                        }

                        // file_m2 = rm_count, sc_count, in_count
                        else if (strpos($filename , $file_m2)) {
                            $query =  "INSERT INTO tbltest (rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,rm_count,sc_count,in_count) 
                                   VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$data11','$data12','$data13')
                                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rm_count=values(rm_count),sc_count=values(sc_count),in_count=values(in_count)";  
                        }
                         //file_m3 = en_count, co_count, ve_count, ed_count
                        else if (strpos($filename , $file_m3)) { 
                            $query =  "INSERT INTO tbltest (rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,en_count,co_count,ve_count,ed_count) 
                                   VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$data14','$data15','$data16','$data17')
                                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE en_count=values(en_count),co_count=values(co_count),ve_count=values(ve_count),ed_count=values(ed_count)";
                        }
                         // file_m4 = rm_count, sc_count, in_count,en_count, co_count, ve_count, ed_count
                        else if (strpos($filename , $file_m4)) {
                            $query =  "INSERT INTO tbltest (rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,rm_count,sc_count,in_count,en_count,co_count,ve_count,ed_count) 
                                   VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$data11','$data12','$data13','$data14','$data15','$data16','$data17')
                                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rm_count=values(rm_count),sc_count=values(sc_count),in_count=values(in_count)
                                   en_count=values(en_count),co_count=values(co_count),ve_count=values(ve_count),ed_count=values(ed_count)";
                        }

                        mysql_query ($query,$connect);
                    }  //if   
                } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"|"));  //do
            } //found   
        } // if exist
    } //if server
?>
```

PROBLEM: I can successfully upload any file. Problem is, if the filename has **m1** or **m4** on it, I cannot insert the values(from the csv) on the database table. While files with **m2** and **m3** successfully inserts the values(from the csv) into the database table. When I do `echo $query;` the result are correct values.

Comment: Cz this is `if (!$found) {` alwys true. Cz no variable define for `$found`

Comment: I have a `$found=0;` variable declared

Comment: `$found = 0` and having a condition of `if(!$found)` will always be true because the system will read it like `if($found == 0)`, which is the same as `if($found == false)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that strpos() returns the starting position index of $filename in $file_m1 (if found), otherwise it returns false. So in this code, strpos() sometimes returns 0 (which is then coerced to false when referenced in the if statement). That’s why the code doesn’t work properly.

The correct solution would be to explicitly compare the value returned by strpos() to false as follows:

Replace all the:

```
strpos($filename , $file_m1)
```

and other expression like this To:

```
strpos($filename , $file_m1) !== false
```

Note that we used the !== operator, not just the != operator. If we use !=, we’ll be back to the problem that 0 is coerced to false when referenced in a boolean expression, so 0 != false will evaluate to false.